# How do i access the env of Capistrano 3?

Tags: capistrano3

I am executing the following command:

```
cap staging assets:precompile
```

How do I access the variable env in my Capistrano deploy.rb?

where env is equal to 'staging' in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fetch(:stage)` or `#{stage}` in a string for example like this:

```
  task :sunspot_stop do
      run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop RAILS_ENV=#{stage}"
  end
```

Comment: I actually had to do fetch(:stage), thanks.  Please edit your answer.